# A little git trouble

Tags: git, merge, commit, push

I'm using git with my friend.
I did a few commits and my friend didn't update his local repo and pushed with -f arugment:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Now in the git server (github) my commits are destroyed and the latest commit is my friends. But I have a history of commits locally. Can I somehow merge them back to the master? Or I have to do it by hands with newest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your friend did change something already published on a public repository. See http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html. Start by burning your friend.

Normally a git pull should trigger a merge on your side. You can always copy your whole repository as backup in case. Also you can simply copy the changes from your latest version to a new checkout and commit all of them as a single commit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think I'd do force your commits to be published to github (thus re-writing the history again), have your "friend" pull your changes, rebase his changes, then push his changes up. This way, you get both your changes to the same place.

A good rule of thumb is to **NEVER FORCE A COMMIT TO GITHUB** :) Do it this once to get your repo back to the state it was in before your "friend" messed it up:

```
# on your machine
git push origin master --force

#now your "friend's" working copy is fairy screwed up, so on his machine:
git checkout -b screwed_up #checks out a new branch called screwed_up
git pull origin master # pulls in your changes
git checkout master #checks out his version with his changes
git rebase screwed_up #moves his changes to the end of your changes (see git graphs for more details)
git commit -am 'your message here'
git push origin master #pushes his changes, which are now merged with your changes back to github
```

Answer (score 0):

Pushing back your own local commit is one way (`git push origin master --force`), but it erases your friend's contribution.

You could:

- rename `master` on GitHub (see "[renaming remote git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084273/renaming-remote-git-branch)")
- fetch that "friend_master" branch from GitHub, and rebase it on top of your master, integrating your friend's contributions, and validating them.
- `git push origin master` (recreating master branch with a full content)

Then your friend can simply reset his/her local `master` branch to `origin/master`.