# Renaming remote git branch

Tags: git, github

I have 2 git branches: master and experimental.

Experimental became good, I want to make it the master. I figured I would rename to shuffle things around, but here is what I got:

```
nutebook:Stuff nathan$ git remote rename master old
error: Could not rename config section 'remote.master' to 'remote.old'
```

I use GitHub and Git-Tower.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The following is a guide to rename your master branch. It will work just as easily to rename your experimental branch.

> Here's how I did the renaming.
>
> First, in your working tree, locally rename master to something
>   else.
>
> ```
> git branch -m master old-dev
> ```
>
> Renaming a branch does work while you are on the branch, so
>   there's no need to checkout something else.
>
> Then, locally rename the maintenance branch (2.63-branch) to
>   master:
>
> ```
> git branch -m 2.63-branch master
> ```
>
> Now, time to mess with the remote. Just in case you screw up, you
>   might want to make sure you have a current backup. First, delete the
>   remote's master:
>
> ```
> git push origin :master
> ```
>
> And now, give the remote your new master:
>
> ```
> git push origin master:refs/heads/master
> ```
>
> Update: When creating a new branch, the refs/heads/ prefix is
>   needed on the remote side. If the branch already exists (as master did
>   above) only the branch name is required on the remote side.
>
> ... and your now-renamed old master:
>
> ```
> git push origin old-dev:refs/heads/old-dev
> ```
>
> Finally, delete the old name of your maintenance branch to prevent
>   confusion:
>
> ```
> git push origin :2.63-branch
> ```
>
> Clients will now get the 'new' master branch when they pull.

see [this](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/20080307124544/) site.

Comment: To add to this: when I wanted to rename my 'master' on github, I first had to change the default branch under 'settings' before it would let me delete it (i.e. `git push origin :master`).

Comment: Can you just rename the branch locally and push it to remote and then delete the old one?

Comment: I find the -u flag to push is nice because it sets the upstream tracking of the new remote up for you, e.g. `git push -u origin master` (using git 1.7 I didn't need the full refs/heads prefix)

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to checkout the experimental branch, delete the remote master branch, then push the local experimental one as the new remote master one.

```
// delete the remote master branch by pushing null
// (the space in front of the semicolon) in this branch
git push origin :master
// push local experimental to remote master
git push origin experimental:master
```

Answer (score 1):

`master` is a branch, not a remote like `origin` is. if you want to have your experimental work to your master branch, simply merge it in:

```
git checkout master
git merge experimental
```

Comment: This may give an unwanted result: There might be something on `master` the OP wants to get rid of (if `experimental` is not rebased to the current tip of `master`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Mac user, you can use the GitHub Mac App (https://mac.github.com/) to rename branches.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried to do was rename a remote repo from "master" to "old". To rename a branch on another repo, just delete it with

```
git push <remote> :<branch name>
```

then push it as something else.

Comment: This deletes the commit history of the deleted branch on remote. In many situations with a robust SDLC this is fine. The Ops question exposes that they had 2 unstable/dev branches that couldn't be merged (supposedly), one with a special name "master". The most popular answer keeps an intact history of commit histories of old and new master branches.