# How can you merge on github.com

Tags: github

We have 2 branches named feature-backgrounds and feature-Backgrounds (note the capital B) and this is causing issues with our git client applications (I've tried eclipse GIT, sourcetree and the github mac client) which don't know which branch to talk to. However when I look at the github.com site, it is very easy to tell the difference.

Is there some way I can either rename a branch on github.com or merge the 2 together so that my git client programs are not confused? (or is there a client that wont get confused with case issues?

Comment: Thanks Chris & Von. I ended up using the command line client as Chris suggested by pulling down both branches and merging them into a third which we are doing the development off for the time being. I haven't removed the old branches yet (as I'm not as proficient as I'd like to be with git yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to end up with a single branch at the end, do a pull request on GitHub from one to the other, merge them, and delete the original branch.

Failing that, the github command line clients shouldn't have any issue dealing with this; have you tried that as opposed to using graphical clients?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your branch locally and then on GitHub (by deleting the previous branch and pushing the new one).
See "[Renaming remote git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7084273/6309)" and [this example](https://gist.github.com/pyrat/1195816).

```
git branch -m feature-Backgrounds feature-backgrounds2
git push origin :feature-Backgrounds
git push origin feature-backgrounds2:refs/heads/feature-backgrounds2
```