# git push branch to a new repo with a different name

Tags: git, branch

How can I push a branch to a different repo with a new name for the branch.

For instance I have a branch `feature1` on repo `abc` and I'd like to push to repo `xyz` and make it the master branch.

I tried using [Renaming remote git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084273/renaming-remote-git-branch) but then after doing a git clone on the new repo I got the error message

> git Warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout

Is there a way to specify in the push what I want the destination branch name to be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
git push xyz feature1:master
```

If master already exists, you can clobber it with `-f/--force`, or `+`:

```
git push -f xyz  feature1:master
git push    xyz +feature1:master
```

From the man page (in the examples section at the end):

> ```
>    git push origin +dev:master
>        Update the origin repository’s master branch with the dev branch,
>        allowing non-fast-forward updates. [...]
> ```

Comment: That works great, although if the branch doesnt exist it requires using /refs/heads/master eg. git push xyz feature1:refs/heads/master