# Git script to rebase and squash temporary commits

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-squash

Of the few times I have squashed Git commits,  it took some manual work to pick the previous commits I wanted to squash.

Is there some way to so this automatically - my goal is to squash all previous commits that have not already been pushed to a particular remote branch.

To elaborate, say I have 1 local branch called "dev" and 2 remotes, public and private. I commit and push all I want to the private remote, to a branch called "dev", let's call that `private/dev`. But on the public remote I want to keep things clean and tidy, and to keep one standard branch called "master", let's call that `public/master`. So like I said, for all the commits that have not already made it to the public remote master branch, I want to squash those into one big commit, and the push to public/master

How can I achieve that? Seems complicated.

Comment: Check out https://robots.thoughtbot.com/autosquashing-git-commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply create a temporary branch via `public/master` (with `public` being the name of your public remote, and `master` - for instance - being the destination branch)

And you use [`merge --squash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) (see "[In git, what is the difference between `merge --squash` and `rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309)")

```
 git checkout -b temp public/master
 git merge  --squash dev
 # since merge --squash does not produce a commit:
 git commit -m "squash dev"
 git push public temp:master
 git checkout dev
 git branch -d temp
```

On the colon syntax, see "[git push branch to a new repo with a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106185/6309)" and the [examples section of `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_examples).
It allows for pushing a local branch to a remote one with a different name.

Comment: I hope this works. can you please elaborate on what exactly is happening in each step/command? not sure I actually follow

Comment: for example, can you give the merge result a commit message, which would be used when you looked at the latest version of public/master?

Comment: also what is "git push public tmp:master" - what does the colon syntax mean?

Comment: I updated my question with useful details, I will edit your answer to reflect the details, please correct me if I am mistaken, thanks.

Comment: I got this:

"$ git merge --squash -m "squashed with dev" dev" => 
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

not sure what that means

Comment: I didn't request "not to commit", but I guess it is giving you a chance to commit afterwards and provide a message

Comment: @AlexanderMills Right! `git merge --squash` does not produce a commit. You need an additional `git commit -m`. Edited.

Comment: but do you know what this means: "squash commit -- not updating HEAD" - it seems to not update the index (does not capture files from dev branch for some reason). Even though it says the automatic merge was succesful.

Comment: @AlexanderMills It means it records the merge in the index, but does not commit. files from dev should be there.

Comment: yeah I am not sure, I got it working but a slightly different way, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @AlexanderMills Excellent: What did you use?

Comment: I had to use a 3rd branch to avoid merge conflicts because public/master has deleted files that I remove from public, public/master cannot be merged directly with dev, I have to use a 3rd branch called devtemp where I delete the same files I deleted in master.