# How to push an existing branch into a new repo using git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote

I'm currently working on a project where we have a UI branch and a Services branch (not my branching design).  We now need to separate them into two distinct repos. I am trying to find the best way to do this while preserving the history and not having the new repo track back to the old one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push branch to a new repo with a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105934/git-push-branch-to-a-new-repo-with-a-different-name)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You first have to add the new remote repository:

```
git remote add newrepo https://github.com/name.git
```

Then you could push your branch (yournewbranch) to this repository:

```
git push newrepo yournewbranch:master
```

If the master branch already exists you might force the update or push to an other branch on the new repository

Answer (score 0):

You could simply clone the repo for every branch, and delete all other branches.

For example, to keep the `ui` branch:

```
git clone <url> ui
git remote remove origin
git checkout ui
git branch -D services
```