# Git: How to swap 2 branches both local and remote (Github)

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Can someone give a clear, simple way to swap the names on 2 branches with Git, with Github as remote repository?**

Here's the scenario:

1. I created a **dev** branch off master.
2. After 1 commit on **dev**, I created branch **exp** (experiment).
3. I checked out **dev** again and made 2 more commits.
4. Then I realized I really wanted **exp** to be the branch that made those 2 commits, so I'd like to swap **exp** and **dev**

I'm fairly new at this and I've gone through some of the visual Git tutorials and searched this site and Google, but it's still not clear to me the best or intended way to fix this in Git (and particularly - with a Github remote repo)

---

### My Bad attempts to fix this:

I've tried a few things and made a mess of it - renaming local branches with Git Extensions, but not able to get the remote Github repo to reflect that change. 
I tried making new branches, but can't always get those to reflect in both local and remote (regardless of where I make them).

I finally was able to get everything how I needed it with Git Extensions main *pull* function with "Prune remote branches", which appears to use *fetch* with *--prune* - this reflected remote deletions back to local, and also the *push* function with some force/delete options enabled.

I thought at first I might just be able to reset/move both branches (i.e. move exp up to dev, then reset exp back to the commit that dev was on (2 back), but when trying to reset in Git Extensions, it asks me to choose a soft, mixed, or hard reset - that made me stop and go the other route of trying to rename/create new branches, etc.  Maybe this was the right track - if so, should I have done a soft or hard reset - or doesn't it matter after committing any open changes? I did a lot of searching on that, and even understanding working directory, index, and branch, it still wasn't clear in my case.

---

### Question

There must be better ways to get this done - **how can I easily swap two branches (or rename 2 branches so they effectively swap), in a way that all changes are reflected both locally and remotely (on Github)?**

I would appreciate any insight on why your method is the right or easiest way to go.  Thanks!

---

**Note:** I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084273/renaming-remote-git-branch) about renaming master (or any branch) - but there are a lot of steps there.  I could do that twice, but I find it hard to believe that is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the two branches just to reposition a few commits sounds a bit like picking up a house and spinning it just to unscrew a lightbulb.

I think the easiest thing to do here would be to move the *commits* rather than trying to rename the branches.  One simple way would be to cherry-pick the two commits from `dev` onto `exp`, and then to remove the two commits from `dev`

```
git checkout exp
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of first dev commit>
git cherry-pick <SHA-2 of first dev commit>
```

And then remove the two commits from `dev`:

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Note that if you have already pushed `dev` to GitHub *and* someone else may have pulled the branch, then you should instead revert the two commits:

```
git checkout dev
git revert A^..B
```

Here `A` is the first commit and `B` is the second commit.  Note that `git revert` adds a *new* commit, which in this case will functionally undo the two commits on `dev` which you want to remove.  So `dev` would end up with three commits, but it would be as if the two commits now on `exp` were never made on `dev`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't even consider the complication of someone else already have pulled.  Can you explain why you use the --hard option in the reset?

Comment: @LightCC Doing a hard reset moves the HEAD of the branch back twk commits and also resets the stage and working directory to that commit.  Hence, it really is like nuking the two commits.

Comment: Okay, so the commits are already "safe" because they are in the exp branch, but from the dev branch point of view, you are wanting to completely reset to exp~2, with no staged or unstaged changes.  If instead, I wanted to leave those 2 commits worth of changes available to change, restage, and recommit (as a part of the new dev branch, separate from exp), then I could use --soft, right?

Comment: @LightCC Yes, doing a soft reset, assuming your current working directory is empty and stage also empty, would be a way to recommit those two commits later, possibly with some new changes added.

Answer (score 3):

Create two new branches `exp2`, `dev2` from `exp` and `dev` respectively.

```
$ git checkout exp
$ git branch exp2          # create new branch 'exp2' from 'exp'

$ git checkout dev
$ git checkout -b dev2     # create and checkout to `dev2` branch
```

Delete your local and remote `dev` and `exp` branches.

```
$ git branch -D dev        # delete local 'dev' branch
$ git push origin :dev     # delete remote 'dev' branch

$ git branch -D exp        # delete local 'exp' branch
$ git push origin :exp     # delete remote 'exp' branch
```

Create a new local branch `exp` from `dev2` and push to remote.

```
# make sure you are in 'dev2' branch

$ git checkout -b exp
$ git push origin exp
```

Create a new local branch `dev` from `exp2` and push to remote.

```
$ git checkout exp2        # checkout to 'exp2' so, current branch is 'exp2'
$ git checkout -b dev      # create new branch 'dev' 
$ git push origin dev      # push 'dev' branch to remote
```

Now, if all things are ok then delete local `exp2` and `dev2` branch. (Optional)

```
$ git branch -D dev2      # delete local 'dev2' branch
$ git branch -D exp2      # delete local 'exp2' branch
```

Comment: Hi Sajib - thanks.  This goes beyond what I need for my example, but this shows how to completely swap two branches. This is helpful, if not the simplest answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the commit history  you described as below:

```
A---B---…  master
     \
      C---D---E  dev
      |
     exp
```

You can use below commands:

```
git checkout exp
git merge dev
git push origin exp
git checkout dev
git reset --hard head~2
git push -f origin dev
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
A---B---…  master
     \
      C    dev
       \
        D---E   exp
```

Of cause you can rename branch names, but this way is more efficient.

**Note:** if you are co-work with others and there has new changes on `dev` branch, you can backup the changes in a new branch such as `temp` by `git pull origin dev` and `git checkout -b temp origin/dev` at first. After swapping your local `exp` as `dev`, then you can cherry-pick or merge the changes by other developers from `temp` to `dev`.

Comment: I think you should add a caviat in case `dev` has already been broadcast publicly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, thanks for reminder and I added this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The process is much simpler, just use a *temporary* branch name while renaming, eg.  `todo-dev`:

```bash
git branch --move exp todo-dev
git branch --move dev exp
git branch --move todo-dev dev
git push <remote> exp --set-upstream exp   # upstream was `dev` before  
git push <remote> dev --set-upstream dev   # upstream was `exp` before  

# Repeat the `push` commands for any other remote repos.
```

All the commands above are impervious to the checked-out branch, and do not affect the *working-dir* or the *index* (unlike the `checkout`, `reset` & `cherry-pick` commands).

The whole process is the same, regardless of the remote git-server (ie. GitHub, GitLab or just a local clone).